# OpenCV: Reading video sequences

Tags: opencv

Is there a way of randomly reading video frames in OpenCV....just like arrays are accessed using indexes? Otherwise, if I want to load complete video in CPU or GPU how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `set(int propId, double value)` method on your video capture (also check out the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set)), where `propId` can either be one of the following:

- `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC`: Current position of the video file in milliseconds.
- `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`: 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.
- `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO`: Relative position of the video file: 0 - start of the film, 1 - end of the film.

A small example that plays a video 50 seconds in:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    namedWindow("Frame", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    Mat frame;

    VideoCapture capture(argv[1]);
    if (!capture.isOpened())
    {
        //error in opening the video input
        cerr << "Unable to open video file: " << argv[1] << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 50000);
    for (;;)
    {
        //read the current frame
        if (!capture.read(frame))
        {
            cerr << "Unable to read next frame." << endl;
            cerr << "Exiting program!" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        imshow("Frame", frame);
        waitKey(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).... Solved my problem. Just one more question...would this accessing random frame would be an O(1) complexity operation?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to help you on this one. I couldn't find anything after a quick google search... But it would be quite interesting. So if you happen to find out something, please keep me informed ;)

Comment: I computed time for setting to a desired frame...the result were: frame_index -> time taken (ms) => 0 -> 0.022 ms => 50 -> 37.44 ms => 100 -> 75.48 ms => 400 -> 123.21 ms

Comment: Implies it is an time consuming operation...hey, please have a look at my other question and see if you can help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625487/increasing-stack-memory-for-image-procesing-c-opencv