# Increasing stack memory for Image Procesing (C++ OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, stack-size

is there any way to increase the stack memory for image processing using C++/OpenCV interface?.... I want to load multiple images (lets say around 100 with each image of size roughly 1 MB) into memory and perform parallel computation on them using GPU.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944841/how-to-increase-the-maximum-memory-allocated-on-the-stack-heap

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program?lq=1

Comment: I'm afraid stack has nothing to do with the opencv image manipulations, rather than you should consider heap size because cv::Mat image class is a smart container which allocates memory dynamically, though on a heap not on a stack. And in your case you don't have to worry that 100MB will increase heap size...

Comment: How should I do this => I want to load multiple images (lets say around 100 with each image of size roughly 1 MB) into memory and perform parallel computation on them using GPU?

Comment: There is no general solution, depends on the details. You can start with gpu::GpuMat (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html#gpu-gpumat)