# Computational complexity of openCV algorithms/methods

Tags: opencv

After it came up in a question, I realised, that up to this point I never stumbled upon any information about the computational complexity of the algorithms or methods openCV provides. Are there any articles or information about it? For example (as it came up in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616043/3344078) question), the complexity of reading/accessing a video stream in Landau notation, or any of the algorithm implementation like SIFT/SURF (I only read that the openSURF library is supposed to be more efficient than the openCV implementation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that most of the high-level algorithms are documented, at least with pointer to an academic article, where you can have hints about the complexity of the algorithm

Comment: You're right, that should be true for the high-level algorithms. But what about what about method for reading images or video streams?

Comment: I think OpenCV encapsulate libraries for that, such as libjpeg for jpg images, and ffmpeg or V4L for video stream. Complexity depends on the image/video format